# How to get total size of all files recursively under directory

Tags: linux, hadoop, awk, hdfs

I am using this command to get the files less than 17MB:

```
hadoop fsck /admin_test -files | 
gawk '{if ($2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2 <= 17825792) print $1,$2;}'
```

How can I get the total size of all files less than 17MB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gawk '
    $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2 <= 17825792 {sum += $2; print $1, $2} 
    END {print "sum=", 0+sum}
'
```

Comment: nit-pick: `END...sum+0` in case none of the files match the condition.

Comment: Nice. Why have I not seen that idiom before?

Comment: idk, I think it's a common one.

Answer (score 1):

what about using `du` with the `--threshold=SIZE` arg:

```
       -t, --threshold=SIZE
          exclude entries smaller than SIZE if positive, or entries greater than SIZE if negative
```

something like this:

```
du -sk --threshold=-17825792 /admin_test
```

Comment: It gives error. In hadoop it cannot be used like that